# Getting AJAX to work with Wordpress, keeps returning a response of 0

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Hey i am using canvas to put an image out and save it. I can not get wordpress to make an ajax request. I keep getting back 0 responseText. I have beeen working on this for days and can't seem to get it to work. My page is http://studio-42.com/games.

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.draw-game', function() {

var testCanvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var canvasData = testCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var postData = "canvasData="+canvasData;
var debugConsole= document.getElementById("debugConsole");
debugConsole.value=canvasData;

jQuery.ajax({
url : drawing.ajax_url,
type : 'post',
data : {
action : 'save_the_drawing',
imgBase64: postData,

},
success : function( response ) {
alert(response);
```

Here is my JS

And this one is the PHP code

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'drawing_game_enqueue_scripts' );
function drawing_game_enqueue_scripts() {
if( is_page('games') ) {
wp_enqueue_style( 'drawing-game', plugins_url( '/drawing-game.css', __FILE__ ) );
}
wp_enqueue_script( 'drawing-game', plugins_url( '/drawing-game.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
wp_localize_script( 'drawing-game', 'drawing', array(
'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
));
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_the_drawing', 'save_the_drawing' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_the_drawing', 'save_the_drawing' );
function save_the_drawing() {



$img = $_POST['postData'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$fileData = base64_decode($img);
//saving
$fileName = 'photo.png';
file_put_contents($fileName, $fileData);

}
```

I keep only getting back a 0 and its driving me crazy! Please Help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `die()` at the end of your script. Simply returning or echoing will not suffice.

WordPress by default returns 0 as a return code (0 being no errors detected) if you do not specify a return value (by calling `die()`)

Here's some additional details, and there's more in the WP Codex: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ajax-call-returns-0

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Elliot. I added the die() funtion but now it doesnt work at all. To be more clear, what Im trying to do is to process the img and convert it to a link which is then automatically sent to the comment form and submitted. If a return of 0 is good, then Im on the right track. How do I get it to return the data in the form of a png img or a link?

Comment: Jarod, once you have the link, say `$link = {add code here}` then do `die( $link );` you can also json_encode() your link and then with jQuery retrieve the JSON using `jQuery.parseJSON( responseFromAjax )` if you want to work with more advanced objects than Strings.

Comment: @JarodMeans if the answer did not work, please let me know and I'll update my response again. Otherwise, I would appreciate it if you marked this as resolved.